# Как растянуть элемент на несколько ячеек grid

Tags: python, tkinter

Только начал изучать Tkinter.
Проблема в том, что результат такой: [image: картинка]
мне нужно чтобы Entry не растягивал 1 столбик, а как-бы был сразу на 3-ех столбцах
вот код

```py
import tkinter as tk

def inserting(var):
    entry.delete(0, END)
    entry.insert(0, var)


def deleting():
    entry.delete(0, END)


root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Colors")
root.geometry("350x150")
#root.resizable(width=False, height=False)

title = tk.Label(text="", justify="center")
title.grid()

entry = tk.Entry(justify="center", width=50)
entry.grid()

red = tk.Button(width=15)
red.grid(column=0, row=2)

orange = tk.Button(width=15)
orange.grid(column=1, row=2)

yellow = tk.Button(width=15)
yellow.grid(column=2, row=2)

green = tk.Button(width=15)
green.grid(column=0, row=3)

blue = tk.Button(width=15)
blue.grid(column=1, row=3)

darkBlue = tk.Button(width=15)
darkBlue.grid(column=2, row=3)

purple = tk.Button(width=15)
purple.grid(column=0, row=4)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

используйте `columnspan`

```
entry = tk.Entry(justify="center", width=50)
entry.grid(columnspan = 3)
```